# No results displayed Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have this query which is one of a number of queries I have done, All the other queries works great but this does not display any results. My database has results that meets the request. Someone tell me what could be wrong?

```
<?php include_once "/phpmysqli/config.php" ?>
<?php 
$Week_ID = $teams->WeekID->CurrentValue;
$GKB = $teams->Keeper2->CurrentValue;
$stmt16 = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt16,"SELECT Total_pts FROM keeper_points WHERE PlayerID=? AND WeekNo=?"))
    {
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt16,"ss",$GKB,$Week_ID);
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt16);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt16,$GKB_pts);
      mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt16);
      echo $GKB_pts;
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt16);
     }
?>
```

Comment: Have you done any errorlogging at all? See what function errors?

Comment: Are $GKB and $Week_ID strings, or integers?

Comment: they are integers, could that be the problem?

Comment: It's worth checking that the SQL statement is correct, by running it against your database directly. One thing that jumps out is the table name `keeper_points`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like PlayerID and WeekNo columns may be integers.
If they are, then try passing in the parameters as so:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt16,"ii",$GKB,$Week_ID);
```

Comment: Still no results after changing, is there anything else that could cause this.

Comment: OK. I think the database will convert the values anyway but thought it worth a try!